# Does for loop in c only can have one statement?

Tags: c, for-loop

Ruby's for/in loop can have many statement:

```
for a in 1..2 do
  expression 1
  expression 2
  ..
end
```

But it seems for loop in C can only have one:

```
for (a = 0; a < 10; a ++) expression 1;
```

Is there any way to make multiply statement in the for loop in C?

Comment: You should hurry up and get your C book. You can't just ask questions about every single C construct you run into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, formally speaking all loop statements in C take only *one* statement as the loop body. The same is true for branching statements (like `if`) and virtually all other statements in C.

However, that *one* statement can be a *compound* one. A compound statement begins with `{`, ends with `}` and contains an arbitrary number of nested statements inside. (Note that there's no `;` at the end of compound statement.)

Answer (score 2):

Use braces for the body of the loop:

```
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) 
{
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

This concept extends to other things, like `if`, as well. This should be mentioned right alongside the `if` and `for` themselves in  any book, etc.

Comment: This, but please don't use egyption braces. :-)

Comment: @Dylan that is totally a matter of preference.

Comment: Well, I know this debate well in C++. I've never looked into it in C, so I'll stick with these until I do.

Comment: C, C++, C#, Java.... does it really matter?

Comment: @Dylan: What's "egyption braces"?

Comment: @AndreyT, Among others, http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html. I changed the braces when I added in the book note.

Comment: @Chris - you edited your example code... where is your conviction man!? ;-)

Comment: @Dylan, I thought it might have been looked at differently in C, didn't want to start a debate, and decided it wasn't worth the edit to put back when it's just preference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn C syntax.  You put them in a block

```
for (...) {
   expression 1;
   expression 2;
}
```

Comment: Ok, Now I understand, the braces can be omitted if it only have one statement